# Reading unexpected data from rs232 serial port

Tags: c, serial-port

Motorola cpu module connect via rs232 to windows PC. On the module side, 93:05:00:78:2E:64:61:74:77 data write to uart and expecting the read same data on PC side but 8E:12:00:E0:E2:62:90:80:90 data reading from PC COM1. Do you have an idea about the problem? Why data mixing? or why I am reading wrong. Big&little endian problem? I can not solve this.

On the PC side;
I am reading from com port

```
int poll_comport(int comport_number, unsigned char *buf, int size)
{
  int n;

  if(size>4096)
   {
      size = 4096;
   }

  ReadFile(Cport[comport_number], buf, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL);

  return(n);
}
```

I am writing to com port

```
int send_byte(int comport_number, unsigned char byte)
{
  int n;

  WriteFile(Cport[comport_number], &byte, 1, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL);
  if(n<0)
   {
      return(1);
   }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: Wrong baud rate. All serial settings - baudrate, parity, stop bits - must match on both sides.

Comment: Most likely it is a configuration problem as TurboJ says.  Or maybe the clock into serial chip at the Motorola end is not what you expect it to be. Perhaps try some other data: clear the receive buffer before receiving  (memset(buf, 0xA5, size)) send all zeros, check what is received, all 0xff and check etc.

Comment: Thank you Turbo J and William Morris, you are right, problem is baudrate.